# How ViewModel state is automatically updated

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

In an activity, I declared a chronometer

```
Chronometer chronometer = findViewById(R.id.timer);

ChronometerViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ChronometerViewModel.class);
if (viewModel.getStartTime() == null) {
   long startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        viewModel.setStartTime(startTime);
        chronometer.setBase(startTime);
    } else {
        chronometer.setBase(viewModel.getStartTime());
    }
 chronometer.start();
```

ViewModel class

```
public class ChronometerViewModel extends ViewModel {
  @Nullable
  private Long mStartTime;

  @Nullable
  public Long getStartTime() {
    return mStartTime;
  }

  public void setStartTime(final long startTime) {
    this.mStartTime = startTime;
  }
}
```

When I rotated the screen, chronometer automatically resumes from the previous state. But I did not write any code which stores the current state of the timer to ViewModel class on configuration change. How is the state automatically restored?

I am following this google's codelabs [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/index.html#2)

Edit: I was confused with the setBase method of Chronometer. I assumed that my state variable, mStartTime is automatically getting updated to current time that was showing in Chronometer widget. Now I have checked the documentation of setBase method. since mStartTime persists on confirguration change, we can use old value from which Chronometer has started. So Chronometer actually resumes.

Comment: Run the app (choose Step 2 in the Run Configurations dropdown)

Comment: How does ChronometerViewModel object's startTime gets updated with chronometer time.
I don't see the code to set ChronometerViewModel .setStartTime method.@Akhil, @Serj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ViewModel lifecycle** is as below, Android introduced it for the same purpose, so that it can survive configuration changes and doesn't loose state until activity is **finished**

BTW, are you facing any issue because of this behavior?

[image: ViewModel lifecycle]

Answer (score 0):

Your ChronometerViewModel (being a child of ViewModel) does not get destroyed with the orientation change of the Activity.

> ViewModel is a class that is responsible for preparing and managing
>   the data for an Activity or a Fragment. It also handles the
>   communication of the Activity / Fragment with the rest of the
>   application (e.g. calling the business logic classes).
>
> A ViewModel is always created in association with a scope (an fragment
>   or an activity) and will be retained as long as the scope is alive.
>   E.g. if it is an Activity, until it is finished.
>
> In other words, this means that a ViewModel will not be destroyed if
>   its owner is destroyed for a configuration change (e.g. rotation). The
>   new instance of the owner will just re-connected to the existing
>   ViewModel.

I suggest you read the documentation of ViewModel: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel.html